# Array : How to assign object in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

for example i have a function like below

```
        var testName= "";
        testName= $('.test').map(function() {
                    // get text 
                       return $(this).text()
                      // get result as array
                }).get();

            var testResult= {
                name:testName,
            };


        console.log(testResult);
```

The result i can see from my code is

### [image]

Which is not something i wanted.

I want to split those data and assign them one by one

```
"testResult": [
 {
   "name": "test1"
 },
 {
   "name": "Thug life"
 }
]
```

I tired to use for loop to handle those data but it doesn't help

```
for(var i; i < testName.length; i++){
                var testName= testName + [{
                    name:testName[i],
                }];
            }
```

Comment: do you think what you want is a valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them grouped in the result, return a group in your `map`.

```js
var testResult = $('.test').map(function() {
    return {name: $(this).text()};
}).get();

console.log(testResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
```

Or in your format:

```js
var resultObject = {
    testResult: $('.test').map(function() {
        return {name: $(this).text()};
    }).get()
};

console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
```

Comment: i think OP wants the format `"testResult": [
 {
   "name": "test1"
 },
 {
   "name": "Thug life"
 }
]`

Comment: Added that too @guradio

Comment: This is a great answer but can i return more than one field ?  like  "testResult": [ { "name": "test1", "num" : "01" }, { "name": "Thug life" ,  "num" : "02" } ]

Comment: Sure, just add more data into the object, returned in line `return {name: $(this).text()};`, like `return {name: $(this).text(), foo: "bar"};`. @anson920520

Comment: But i need to get those from a for loop? can i do .map() in .map()?

Comment: In general, yes. But I would rethink first if there is any other way. To many loops are not good. I would try to solve this in a better way or see if I can strucure my data in another way. @anson920520

Comment: would you mind to check out my new post? so i can make things clear and reward you some points again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741677/array-put-multple-objects-in-array