# Array: Put multple objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am having a function like below

```js
    var resultObject = {
        testResult: $('.test').map(function() {
            return {name: $(this).text(), no:'1'};
        }).get()
    };
    
    console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>

<div class="test2">1</div>
<div class="test2">2</div>
<div class="test2">3</div>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

The field "no" should be according to the `class="test2"`but it doesn't seem like i can do something like .map() in .map()

**Big Updated!!**

I see there are so many answer below and most of them can solve the issues and I just figured out a way to fix my problem too.

Please let me share it and see if there's anything else i shall improve.

```
var test1= "";  

$(".test" ).each(function( index ) {
    test1 = $(this).text();
});

var test2=  $('.test2').map(function() {
        return {name: $(this).text(), no:test1};
}).get()

var sovCategories = test2;
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution for you. But rethink if one of the posted answers is better for you. You use two loops with `each` and `map` where one loop would be do the same thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second loop. You can use `.eq()` to select the element by the same index.

```js
var resultObject = {
    testResult: $('.test').map(function(i) {
        return {
            name: $(this).text(), 
            no: $('.test2').eq(i).text(), 
        };
    }).get()
};

console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>

<div class="test2">1</div>
<div class="test2">2</div>
<div class="test2">3</div>
```

And just because I had fun, a bit shorter version as arrow function too! ;)

```js
var resultObject = {
    testResult: $('.test').map((i, e) => ({
        name: $(e).text(), 
        no: $('.test2').eq(i).text()
    })).get()
};

console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>

<div class="test2">1</div>
<div class="test2">2</div>
<div class="test2">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below to find the div by the number of the iteration, however this might not be the best thing to do. See below the snippet..

```js
var resultObject = {
        testResult: $('.test').map(function(i) {
            return {name: $(this).text(), no: $('.test2').eq(i).text()};
        }).get()
    };
    
    console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>

<div class="test2">1</div>
<div class="test2">2</div>
<div class="test2">3</div>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

---

Instead of doing above, better change your html and use `data-attributes`.

```
<div class="test" data-no="1">test1</div>
<div class="test" data-no="2">test2</div>
<div class="test" data-no="3">test3</div>
```

Doing it like this, you will be able to pull the data much easier:

```js
var resultObject = {
            testResult: $('.test').map(function(i) {
                return {name: $(this).text(), no: $(this).data("no")};
            }).get()
        };
        
        console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="test" data-no="1">test1</div>
    <div class="test" data-no="2">test2</div>
    <div class="test" data-no="3">test3</div>

    <div class="test2">1</div>
    <div class="test2">2</div>
    <div class="test2">3</div>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: `$($('.test2')[i]).text()`: get a set of jQuery objects, unwrap one of them and re-wrap it in a jQuery object O.o -> `var test2Elements = $(".test2"); test2Elements.eq(i).text()`